# How to calculate a field based on two columns while looping through a spreadsheet

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

I have a table with two columns, and I want to calculate the third.

Column 1 | Column 2 | Calculated Column 
   1     |    1     |      1 
   1     |   1.5    |      2 
   1     |    2     |      3 
   2     |    2     |      1

I am trying to add the third column to my sheet and then in ascending order increment the calculate value.. Once the value in column 1 changes, the incrementing should start over. I was good at this once.. but rusty :) Any help would be awesome

```
  //name the datasets
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //add a new column and name it
  ss.insertColumnAfter(2);
  ss.getRange("C1").setValue("Tier");

  //Get the first store number and result space number
  var atvStr = ss.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var strNbrR = ss.getRange("A2:A9000").getValues();
  var rslt = ss.getRange("C2:C9000").getValues();

  //get the last filled row and +1 to go on to the next
  var line=ss.getLastRow()+1;

  for (i in strNbrR) {

    if (strNbrR[i] = atvStr) {
      ss.getRange(line).setValue("1");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
function testMe(){
  //name the datasets
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //add a new column and name it
  ss.insertColumnAfter(2);

  //Get the first store number and result space number
  var strNbrR = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var rsltRng = ss.getRange("C2:C");
  var rsltVals = rsltRng.getValues();

  var newValue = 1;

  for ( i in strNbrR) {
    if (i >1 ){
      if (strNbrR[i][0] !== strNbrR[i - 1][0]) {
        ++newValue;
      }
    }

    rsltVals[i][0] = newValue;
  }
  rsltRng.setValues(rsltVals);
}
```

It will increment the value placed in Column C if the value in A is not the same as the value in cell A in the previous row.

Comment: I poorly explained my issue, but I was able to edit your code to work for me. Thanks for the help!